# Create a 1x1 texture in SDL 2.0

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

In C# and XNA, you can create a 1x1 texture like this:

```
Texture2D white_pixel;
white_pixel = new Texture2D(GraphicsDevice, 1, 1);
white_pixel.SetData<Color[]>(new Color{ Color.White });
// Sorry if I got the syntax wrong, it's been a while
```

Then later on, you can arbitrarily draw the pixel to any size and color by doing this:

```
spriteBatch.Begin();
spriteBatch.Draw(white_pixel, new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), Color.Whatever);
spriteBatch.End();
```

What is the equivalent in SDL?

```
SDL_Texture *tex = nullptr;
SDL_CreateTexture(renderer,
                               Uint32        format, // What do I put here
                               int           access, // and here
                               1
                               1);
// Not sure if this is correct
SDL_SetTextureColorMod(tex,
                       255,
                       255,
                       255)
SDL_Rect rect;
rect.x = 0;
rect.y = 0;
rect.w = 10;
rect.h = 10;
SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, tex, nullptr, &rect);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGB24`/`SDL_PIXELFORMAT_BGR24` for `format` and `SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STATIC` for `access` would be a good start.

Or you could just draw a colored rectangle directly via [`SDL_SetRenderDrawColor()`](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SetRenderDrawColor) and [`SDL_RenderFillRect()`](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderFillRect).